# Sharing files between Windows 8.1 x64 host and VMware Ubuntu (Lubuntu) 13.10 x86 guest

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8.1, vmware-player, lubuntu, ubuntu-13.10

I have tried to install a small version of Ubuntu's latest version in a virtual machine using VMware Player, [using a Lubuntu 32 bit mini.iso](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Documentation/MinimalInstall#Downloading) to keep the file size and performance requirements down. Basically a "command line install" with core components:

```
sudo -i
apt-get install lubuntu-core
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get autoclean
rm /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb
reboot
```

Once the OS is all setup I install VMware's tools. After shutting down and enabling file-sharing, I don't see a mount point anywhere for the folder I shared. (`d:\projects\` in this case)

I'm more familiar with using Sun's VirtualBox which also is a bit quirky with file sharing, and with that I had to use something along the lines of: `sudo leafpad /etc/fstab` and add this line:

```
travis /media/sf_travis vboxsf defaults,rw,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
```

I'm not sure what I need to do to get it working. Unity and clipboard sharing don't work either, but it's the file sharing that I really need.

**Update #1: One (or all) of these intermediate commands partially resolves the issue**

I tried [this set of commands](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/install-vmware-tools-on-ubuntu-edgy-with-vmware-553/):

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking stop
sudo rmmod pcnet32
sudo rmmod vmxnet
sudo depmod -a
sudo modprobe vmxnet
sudo /etc/init.d/networking start
```

(both networking stop & start commands errored, but the rest appeared to work)

Then [this set](https://askubuntu.com/a/306517/443):

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-virtual
sudo apt-get install linux-image-virtual
sudo dpkg-reconfigure open-vm-tools

sudo vmware-config-tools.pl -d --clobber-kernel-modules=vmhgfs
```

Then I found [this KB article](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&docTypeID=DT_KB_1_1&externalId=1008071), and ran:

```
sudo vmware-user
```

Finally this command works!

```
sudo vmware-hgfsmounter .host:/projects ~/Projects/
```

So now my question is, **how do I get `vmware-user` to run correctly on startup?** I tried adding it to a `~/.xsession` file (which didn't exist) but it doesn't seem to fix it.

Comment: Did you read this in the Help and have you checked this in your VM: **View the shared folder. On Linux guests, shared folders appear** **under /mnt/hgfs. On Solaris guests, shared folders** **appearunder /hgfs.**

Comment: I didn't see that In the help, but `/mnt/hgfs` is empty.